# Inject Object on deployed REST service

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey, osgi

I'm developing a REST API in an Osgi bundle. I'm using Jersey to deploy the services into a jetty container with a javax servlet for each class with REST services.

Each class has an attribute like this

```
Private DBInterface dbInterface;
```

With setters and getters, and I need to inject the object from another bundle once the service is deploy (in runtime).
So anyone know a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

PD: I'd like to do it without declaring the service as singleton so every REST request is answered from another instance of the service (actual stateless REST)

Update: The web.xml code I use to deploy the service is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mypackage.MyServiceClass</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is the exact reason why you do not want to declare the service as singleton? I think you can register objects to Jersey so they will be provided as REST service. You do not have a chance to define a factory or something that is used to instantiate an object for each request. Another question: How is the object in the other bundle instantiated? What technology or mechanism do you use to instantiate it? Do you do it in an Activator or with a special technology? What is the event that causes the other bundle to instantiate that object?

Comment: Is an activator yes. I instantiate the other object when the bundle that contains it is started, in the activator that object is "configured" and then I need to inject it to the REST service. I thought there were someway to say to this service to take that object or to use Jersey, jetty or another bundle or library to inject the object every  time the service is instantiated

Comment: Why do you want to instantiate the service multiple times? Why is it not good if you instatiate it ones and instantiate the part that is different for every request as a local variable inside your function? How do you register your service to Jersey? Do you configure it in a webapp web.xml or you use HTTP service to register it programmatically? I have a feeling that the solution would be pretty simple for you but it would be nice to know a bit more before an answer.

Comment: The thing is that as it's a REST service, the scope is on request, meaning that every request on that service is answered by a diferent instance of the service. I configure the deploy in the web.xml using a javax servlet, I'm updating the question with the web.xml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to say you should register that object in the other bundle activator as an OSGi service. In that case you will be able to access it from almost everywhere.

The other question is: how to access it from the other side? There are many possibilities, some of them are better, some of them are worse.

**A simple but not really nice solution:**

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
// Getting the service and using it based on the bundle
```

The problem with this solution that for every request you will have to get the OSGi service from OSGi service registry based on filters and unget it after the function call is an unnecessary overhead.

**Solution based on ServiceTracker:**

If you use a service tracker you will face the problem that you have to open it and close it somewhere. Opening in the constructor could be a solution, however you will not find a place in your rest class where you can close it. A solution can be that you create a Servlet listener, you open and close the the tracker there and take the service tracker into the servlet context attribute map. In your REST function you can access the servlet context and get the service tracker in each call, than you can call tracker.getService(). That function will give back the object you need or null if it is not registered yet.

**Solution that does not have the necessity to put OSGi related code into REST class:**

It is a possibility that you do not want to use ServiceTracker in your REST code as you do not want to depend on OSGi there. In this case you can use a very simple library I implemented :). It is available at https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-servicereference.

The methodology is the same. You write a Listener that:
 - Creates a ServiceReference
 - You call the getProxtInstance of the serviceReference into the ServletContext
 - You get the proxy object based on the interface you provided in your REST function and call the methods on it.

ServiceReference was implemented as part of a Blueprint implementation. Therefore it works in the same way as  tag works in a blueprint XML file. You can instantiate a service reference and open it (after opening OSGi services will be tracked). You can get an object that implements the necessary interfaces (provided by you) with the getProxyInstance method.

When a function call is made to the object based on your interface:

- If an OSGi service is available the function call will be delegated to that service
- If no OSGi service is available the function call will hold until a timeout (simple thread.wait). If there is an OSGi service before the timeout the function call will be delegated. If not, a ServiceUnavailableException will be thrown. You can override the timeout behaviour by setting a different timeout handler for the ServiceReference object.

A normal function call is like this:

caller -> OSGiService.function

A function call via ServiceReference Proxy object looks like this:

caller -> ServiceReference.proxyObject -> OSGiService.function (if OSGiService is available)

Now the solution in practice:

You should write a listener for the web application:

```
private Reference reference;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
    BundleContext bundleContext = (BundleContext) servletContext.getAttribute("osgi-bundlecontext");

    try {
        Filter filter = bundleContext.createFilter("(objectClass=" + MyInterface.class.getName() + ")");

        // MyInterface is the interface the OSGi service implements (there can be multiple) and the timeout until function calls will wait is 5s.
        reference = new Reference(bundleContext, new Class<?>[] { MyInterface.class }, filter, 5000);

        // Opening the reference is necessary to track services
        reference.open();

        // Taking the proxy object into the servlet context attributes
        servletContext.setAttribute("myService", reference.getProxyInstance());
    } catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    if (reference != null) {
        reference.close();
        sce.getServletContext().removeAttribute("myService");
    }
}
```

After you have this listener you can get the proxy object like the following everywhere in your codes (where you can access the servlet context):

```
MyInterface myService = servletContext.getAttribute("myService");
myService.foo();
```

Comment: We are interested in the last solution you proposed, however we are finding hard to understand how that library works. The Reference instance you create receive the http requests for the services and then wait till the service instance is created or something like that?

Comment: updated the answer to have more information. If something is not clear, please let me know. I think I will link this stackoverflow question as an example from the readme file of the ServiceReference page. Please check the README and the javadoc of Reference class for more information as well.